# How is revision works internally?

Tags: revisions

I'm curious about wordpress revision feature. I want to implement this revision feature in my own php app. How is logic behind this revision feature?

Thanks.

Comment: All of the logic behind Revisions can be found in wp-includes/revision.php Link: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/revision.php A high level overview of Revisions is available in the Codex. Link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Revisions

Comment: I have read that https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/revision.php but still could not understand it. Could you explain it in noob-developer-language? Thanks.